# PostgreSQL: description of the function

Tags: postgresql

Using:

```
SELECT  * FROM information_schema.routines
```

or

```
SELECT  * FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc
```

I can get the list of system function.
Does exists the way to get the description, or even better the classification, of the functions?
Like [here](http://www.leadum.com/downloads/dbscribe/samples/postgresql/web_modern/schema/main/414003199.html) or [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-info.html).

I don't believe, that somebody typing this by hands :)

Thanks!

Comment: How can I get the description of the system functions through SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `psql` shell you can get similar information with

```
\daS

                                                                                 List of aggregate functions
   Schema   |      Name      |      Result data type       |        Argument data types         |                      
------------+----------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------------
 pg_catalog | array_agg      | anyarray                    | anyelement                         | concatenate aggregate
 pg_catalog | avg            | numeric                     | bigint                             | the average (arithmet
 pg_catalog | avg            | double precision            | double precision                   | the average (arithmet
....
```

You can see what the `psql` shell does to get this information by starting the shell with the `-E` argument:

```
********* QUERY **********
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  p.proname AS "Name",
  pg_catalog.format_type(p.prorettype, NULL) AS "Result data type",
  CASE WHEN p.pronargs = 0
    THEN CAST('*' AS pg_catalog.text)
    ELSE
    pg_catalog.array_to_string(ARRAY(
      SELECT
        pg_catalog.format_type(p.proargtypes[s.i], NULL)
      FROM
        pg_catalog.generate_series(0, pg_catalog.array_upper(p.proargtypes, 1)) AS s(i)
    ), ', ')
  END AS "Argument data types",
  pg_catalog.obj_description(p.oid, 'pg_proc') as "Description"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc p
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE p.proisagg
  AND pg_catalog.pg_function_is_visible(p.oid)
ORDER BY 1, 2, 4;
**************************
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but I need to get the 'Description' by SQL... How do you think - this is possible?

Comment: O even beter - get all this table using some SQL Query.

Comment: Thanks! The query - is the perfect solution! I will study it to understand how it works.

Comment: @YuriyVelichko The detailed description you linked to is part of the documentation. It's generated from SGML files in the PostgreSQL source tree, and is not available within the PostgreSQL server its self.